# Google results only showing links of my main page

Tags: html, seo

I have a website futbolpasionatlanta.com that has several pages that are internally linked.  For some reason my google results are all showing my linked websites but my main page the index.php or just www.futbolpasionatlanta.com is showing up in the results.

Any ideas what I can do to correct this?

Is is something I would change on in my head tag?

Thanks,

Comment: how long since you've submitted the website? do you use js for navigation at all? do you use google webmasters tools and if so do you get any errors there? do you use sitemap and have you submitted it to be index as well?

Comment: submitted about an hour ago.  No must of the navigation is done through php.  My google webmaster tools have not populated any info yet.  And I did choose index.

Comment: It takes time, often even several days to get all of your data indexed by google... So I would suggest putting up a sitemap, you can get it automatically generated here: http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/, submit it via webmasters tools and give it couple of days

Answer (score 1):

If you want to encourage Google to crawl and index deeper into your site you should try to get incoming links directly to those inner pages. The higher the quality of those links, the better.

Comment: what if I only want it to do my index page?

Comment: That would be silly. Search engines don't rank websites, they rank web *pages*. If you want all of your pages to rank well you have to promote them equally. That includes getting links to them directly.

Answer (score 0):

It might take some time before Google index your whole site. It will eventually be indexed.

For your next question:
You can use robots.txt and submit it in webmaster tools if you haven't done that yet. This can be used to block some pages:

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449